# Traducción en app android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En mi aplicación, he traducido los @String a español e inglés. El problema que tengo es que no quiero que cambien según el idioma del sistema opertivo como tal, sino según una variable que yo tengo:

```
 countryES =("ES".equals(Locale.getDefault().getCountry())|| "es".equals(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
```

Es decir, quiero que si el locale es "es_XX" o "xx_ES" esté en español y, en el resto de casos inglés.
Por ello, quería cambiar la configuración del locale, de la siguiente manera:

```
if(countryES)
{
    //Cambiar el locale a es_ES
} 
else
{
     //Cambiar el locale a en_US
}
```

Lo que quiero decir con esto es que no quiero cambiar el idioma según el S.O, sino según una variable que he creado yo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Tu duda es como cambiar el valor de Locale?
De ser asi, revisa en el sitio de [AndroidDevelopers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html?hl=es)

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo:

`Locale localizacion = new Locale("es", "ES"); 
    Locale.setDefault(localizacion);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = localizacion;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`